# Every Element of $\mathbb F_p$ is a Square in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ if $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$

Tags: number-theory

How can we show that every element of $\mathbb F_p$ is a square in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ if $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ is a prime?

This comes from the first paragraph of Koblitz's "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms" on page 61, self-study.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to improve your question. You should add context, such as any work you have done on the problem or specific ares where you are unclear.

Comment: There are no improvements to be made. Short of a bunch of hard to quantify algebraic doodling and research on Legendre symbols, I've come up with nothing concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need the condition that $p\equiv 3 \text{(mod }4)$, only that $p$ is odd. Let $F=\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$; clearly it suffices to show that the units of $\mathbb{F}_p\subset F$ are all squares.

Note that $F^\times$ is cyclic; indeed, recall that a finite abelian group is cyclic if and only if there is at most one subgroup of order $k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence suppose there are subgroups $E_1,E_2\leqslant F^\times$ with $|E_1|=k=|E_2|$. The polynomial $x^k-1\in F[x]$ has $E_1\cup E_2$ as roots, but also has at most $k$ roots in $F$ since $F$ is a field, so we must have $E_1=E_2$, and hence $F^\times$ is indeed cyclic. Note that we can use the same argument to show that $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic.

Thus let $\theta\in F^\times$ a generator for $F^\times$, and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ a generator for $\mathbb{F}_p^\times\subset F^\times$. Note that it suffices to show that $\alpha$ is a perfect square, for every element of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is of the form $\alpha^k$ for some $k$. Now, since $\theta$ is a generator for all of $F^\times$, $\alpha=\theta^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus we just need to show that $m$ is even.

But now recall $|F^\times|=p^2-1$, so the order of $\theta$ is $p^2-1$, and $|\mathbb{F}_p^\times|=p-1$, so the order of $\alpha$ is $p-1$. We have $1=\alpha^{p-1}=\theta^{m(p-1)}$, so $p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$ divides $m(p-1)$.

This means that $p+1$ divides $m$, and so since $p+1$ is even by hypothesis we are done. Indeed, we have that $\alpha=(\theta^{m/2})^2$ is a perfect square, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof which does not use the cyclicity of $F^\times$, nor the characterization of cyclic groups mentioned in Atticus' answer.

Let $F$ be a field with $q$ elements, where $q$ is odd. Then, $x\in F^\times $ is a square if and only if $x^{(q-1)/2}=1$.

Indeed, by Lagrange theorem, non zero squares are roots of $X^{(q-1)/2}-1\in F[X]$. Now, apply first isomorphism theorem to $x\in F^\times \mapsto x^2\in F^\times$ shows that there are $(q-1)/2$ nonzero squares, and we are done.

Now assume $q=p^2.$ It is known that $\mathbb{F}_p\subset \in F$, and that nonzero elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfy $x^{p-1}=1$ (Lagrange again, for example).

But $(q-1)/2=(p-1)(p+1)/2$. Thus, if $x$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, then $x^{(q-1)/2}=1$ and $x$ is a square in $F^\times$.